# How to make my entire Wordpress theme to support RTL direction?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woothemes

I have purchased a ecommerce theme and I would like to change the direction from LTR to RTL. 
I went through "http://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support".
But in there I don't know where to add the attributes exactly!
I would be thankful if somebody can give me a help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those changes should be applied to the theme's stylesheets (`.css` files). However there's no general way to achieve that because some JavaScript libraries/plugins should be changed as well. Perhaps it's better hire someone to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.You may be right. But as I talked to the theme developer(the company from whom I purchased the theme), they claimed that it is not a difficult task to do so. I suppose by reversing the details in the css file, this is doable as said in the following link.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support

Comment: It's all css. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/. You might need to float elements a bit differently as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Steven. I am working on it ;)